# how to assert that fastAPI cache is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, fastapi

So I'm writing a function that use fastAPI cache to avoid making a bunch of post calls, then I'm wondering if is possible to write a test to validate that the functions is just called once and then reuse the cached value.

```
from fastapi_cache.decorator import cache

@cache(expire=60)
async def get_auth_token() -> str:
    ## just to exemplify
    return "token"


class TestAuth(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_get_token_success(self):
        """Test get token"""

        # success
        _token = await get_auth_token()
        assert _token is not None
        assert _token == "token"


        # here is the trick
        # calling again should not call post again
        _token = await get_auth_token()
        mock_post.assert_called_once()
```

but I'm getting this error

```
 AssertionError: Expected 'post' to have been called once. Called 2 times.
```

Comment: When you mock the function you replace it with a new function - and since a decorator is "just" a function wrapping another function and returning the new function, you're replacing the caching function. I'd instead either test against a timer with very high resolution (could be platform dependent) or just a long, randomly generated string (having a collision that would break the test would be the same as generating the same token multiple time in production, so - ignorable). You can then use `freezegun` to verify whether the token changes after the cache should have expired as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: return token with timestamp, that you can check timestamp to verify whether it is get from function or cache.

For example:

```py
import time
from fastapi_cache.decorator import cache

@cache(expire=60)
async def get_auth_token() -> str:
    ## just to exemplify
    return str(time.time())


class TestAuth(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_get_token_success(self):
        """Test get token"""
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        # success
        token1 = await get_auth_token()
        assert token1 is not None
        assert timestamp <= token1 <= str(time.time())


        # here is the trick
        # calling again should not call post again
        token2 = await get_auth_token()
        assert token1 == token2

        # check expire
        time.sleep(60)
        token3 = await get_auth_token()
        assert token3 != token1
```

Comment: good idea! 

on all the places where I have used cache I just simply assume it works (because do so) but this question is pure curiosity of how to test it in a proper pythonic way;

appreciate the response